# keras.engine.training.Model.compile() the parameter --loss = dice_loss -- metric= dice_loss are not same

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I write the ResUnet model in keras, but when I train the model, I use the code
`m.compile(optimizer= sgd, loss = Dice_coef_loss, metrics=[Dice_coef, Dice_coef_loss])` the display is not the same.

code in under:

```
G  = MyResUnet.MyLiverDataGenerator.imageSegmentationGenerator( tarin_image_xmls ,  train_batch_size,  n_classes , 
input_height , input_width , input_channel, output_height , output_width , mode ='train')
sgd =keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0005, nesterov=True)

m = Models.ResUnet.ResUnet( n_classes , input_height=input_height, 
input_width=input_width  ,input_channel=input_channel )  # 这边没问题
m.summary()



m.compile(optimizer= sgd, loss = Dice_coef_loss, metrics=[Dice_coef, Dice_coef_loss])
m.fit_generator(G, samples_per_epoch = steps_per_epochs , epochs = 30,verbose = 1,
                # validation_data = G_valid, nb_val_samples = steps_per_epochs_valid,
                callbacks =  [modelCheckpoint,tensorboard],initial_epoch=0)
```

the code can be run and train, but the display is not true. 【set batch_size = 1】

```py
Epoch 1/30

    1/37739 [..............................] - ETA: 94:40:45 - loss: 2.6937 - Dice_coef: 0.1626 - Dice_coef_loss: 0.8374
    2/37739 [..............................] - ETA: 48:02:00 - loss: 2.6776 - Dice_coef: 0.1787 - Dice_coef_loss: 0.8213
    3/37739 [..............................] - ETA: 32:27:13 - loss: 2.7020 - Dice_coef: 0.1543 - Dice_coef_loss: 0.8457
    4/37739 [..............................] - ETA: 24:39:58 - loss: 2.7336 - Dice_coef: 0.1227 - Dice_coef_loss: 0.8773
    5/37739 [..............................] - ETA: 19:59:52 - loss: 2.7566 - Dice_coef: 0.0997 - Dice_coef_loss: 0.9003
    6/37739 [..............................] - ETA: 16:53:33 - loss: 2.7729 - Dice_coef: 0.0834 - Dice_coef_loss: 0.9166
    7/37739 [..............................] - ETA: 14:40:23 - loss: 2.7419 - Dice_coef: 0.1144 - Dice_coef_loss: 0.8856
    8/37739 [..............................] - ETA: 12:59:53 - loss: 2.7560 - Dice_coef: 0.1003 - Dice_coef_loss: 0.8997
```

the loss need to be same as the dice_coef_loss!

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem of the solution.
I let all conv to add kernel_regularizer = l2(0.001), but the dice_loss is unfer the 1,and finnaly limit to 0, kernel_regularizer will affect this